Accessing GitHub without external hardware
I received a message from GitHub that I "will need to enable two-factor authentication on your account before November 08, 2024, or be restricted from account actions".  GitHub recommends "Authenticator apps and browser extensions like 1Password, Authy, Microsoft Authenticator, etc".  When I click through to those apps, it appears that Authy and Microsoft Authenticator are available only for mobile devices.  Although 2FAS has a browser extension, it is not clear to me if this replaces or only complements a mobile application.  I think 1Password can be used without a smartphone, but I'm not sure.
Before I ask my employer to provide me with either a smartphone, a security key, or a 1Password license, I want to make sure what is needed (there is no point in paying for a 1Password license if I still can't use it without a smartphone — we already use keepass throughout the organisation).  Is it possible to have unrestricted access to GitHub without using a mobile device?  How?  Are there free (open source) alternatives that I can use?

Two-factor authentication (2FA) works with the open-source desktop software keepassxc.  Via the context menu of the relevant entry, one can first "Set up TOTP" and enter the code proposed by GitHub.  One can then copy the TOTP-generated code into the browser.

As you discovered, this appears to be nothing more than security theater.  Anyone can write a few lines of code that will automatically generate the required 2FA key.  It appears all Microsoft's 2FA implementation does, in this case, is annoy legitimate users and waste their time.  The implementation appears to do nothing to improve actual security or do anything to actually protect the integrity of open source projects.

@EndAntisemiticHate Yes, I did think it defeats the point of 2FA, but as this is Software Recommendations (original Web Apps) and not Security.SE, I decided not to go into that.
